# Roblox data stores not updating data

Tags: lua, roblox

I have been stuck for the past couple of days with the data not saving, my code is not giving any errors and from what I can see it should work. Here is the code:

```
local DataStore = game:GetService("DataStoreService"):GetDataStore("PlayerStats001")


-- Function to make the leaderstats
function onPlayerJoin(player)

    local Leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", player)
    Leaderstats.Name = ("leaderstats")

    local leadermoney = Instance.new("IntValue", Leaderstats)
    leadermoney.Name = ("Money")


    local leaderrescues = Instance.new("IntValue", Leaderstats)
    leaderrescues.Name = ("Rescues")


    local key = "player-" .. player.userId

    local savePoints = {}
    savePoints = DataStore:GetAsync(key)

    if savePoints then
        print("Old leaderstats")
        -- Has been to game before, save format = {money, rescues}
        leadermoney.Value = savePoints[1]
        leaderrescues.Value = savePoints[2]
    else
        print("New leaderstats")
        leadermoney.Value = 25000
        leaderrescues.Value = 0
        local valuesToSave = {leadermoney.Value, leaderrescues.Value}
        DataStore:SetAsync(key, valuesToSave)
    end

end

-- Saves player data
function save(player)
    print("Started save")
    local key = "player-" .. player.userId
    local valuesToSave = {player.leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Money").Value , player.leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Rescues").Value}
    DataStore:SetAsync(key, valuesToSave)
    print("Finished save", valuesToSave[1], valuesToSave[2])
end

function playerLeaves(player)
    save()
end

-- Runs the save function if a client requests a save
game.Lighting.RemoteEvents.Save.OnServerEvent:Connect(save)

-- Runs the playerLeaves function if a player leaves
game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(save)

-- Runs the onPlayerJoin function when a player joins
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(onPlayerJoin)
```

When I run it (I have a local script in starter GUI which works):

```
function autoSaveRequester()
    print("Started auto save function.")
    while wait(15) do
        print("Finnished wait")
        game.Lighting.RemoteEvents.Save:FireServer()
    end
end

spawn(autoSaveRequester)
```

it outputs the same value as before I change it and not the new one, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the old value you are seeing the default case of "New leaderstats"? Could it be that DataStores don't like that you're giving it an array of information?

Have you tried saving the data as a string instead? It can be pretty easy to serialize a table of data to a json string using HttpService:JSONEncode() and then when you want to load it back into a table using HttpService:JSONDecode().

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because of this line;

```
game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(save)
```

You jump straight to the save function, instead of the PlayerRemoving, as well as not specifying a player.

Update that line to this:

```
game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(playerLeaves)
```

If this helped, make sure to upvote! If this answered your question, don't forgot to press the tick!

If you need anything else, comment below.

Ross.